# Kiosk or 'Receipt' Printing in Chrome OS/Chrome OS Flex

Tags: google-chrome, printing, kiosk, google-chrome-os, kiosk-mode

We have an application we currently run in Chrome browser on Ubuntu and Windows using PrintNode. We'd like to run our application ChromeOS to move away from Linux and Windows, but our the printing of our app requires no user interaction. It appears Chrome browser on Chrome OS forces a Print Dialog/Prompt to the user to confirm the print job. Does anyone know how to suppress this? In the past on Windows/Linux we've leveraged "--kiosk-printing" in Chrome through properties of the desktop shortcut, but this doesn't appear to be possible in the browser in ChromeOS.

Does anyone have an ideas on how to bypass the print dialog in ChromeOS?